# Creating a customer portal user via apex

Tags: customer-portal

Site.createPortalUser call is available in apex everywhere or we can only use it inside SiteRegisterController.cls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm

These are Site classes and you can use outside SiteRegisterController and in  any apex class.You need not have this in only SiteRegisterController.cls .

SiteRegisterController.cls  this is just an example class from salesforce which is for reference .You can make your own apex class and have Site classes.